# Join line to previous line if it doesn't start with a timestamp in UNIX shell

Tags: regex, awk, text-processing

I have a tool which outputs logs with a timestamp prefix, however log entries may contain newlines. I would like to merge any lines without a timestamp with the prior line.

Example:

```
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two
lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines with a twist
[19] to confuse you"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

Using awk I could do something like this to merge lines that don't begin with a [ brace:

`awk -v RS="[" 'NR>1{$1=$1; print RS, $0}'`

However you can see where this fails on the "twist" line above. The "twist" line starts with a [ which isn't part of a timestamp.

Is there a way to use a regular expression for that timestamp prefix instead? Or is there a better command line tool for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following written and tested with shown samples on site https://ideone.com/PXVCh2

```
awk '
{
  printf("%s%s",$0~/^\[ [0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/\
          ?(FNR!=1?ORS:""):OFS,$0)
}
END{ print "" }
' Input_file
```

As per Ed sir's comment added a print new line statement to add a new line at last of Input_file in case it's already doing it one could ommit that part then.

Note: I have written this on mobile; sorry I can't judge how it's looking wise on big screen so I have divided a single of printed line into 2 lines here

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your real problem is actually that your quoted strings can contain newlines and so this GNU awk solution (for multi-char RS) to look for quoted strings might be more robust than looking for timestamps at the start of lines:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub("\n"," ",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines with a twist [19] to confuse you"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

That would behave better than checking for lines starting with a timestamp if your quoted string can contain a timestamp which might appear at the start of a line, e.g. (note the timestamp within the `"four lines with a twist...` block):

```
$ cat file
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two
lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "four lines with a twist
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] to confuse you
repeatedly and
in ""horrible"" ways"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{ORS=gensub("\n"," ","g",RT)} 1' file
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "four lines with a twist [ 2020/08/12 11:40] to confuse you repeatedly and in ""horrible"" ways"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming log contains your example file:

```
$ cat log

[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two
lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines with a twist
[19] to confuse you"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

the following code checks the number of double quotes (") and join two lines if only one double quote is found:

```
$ gawk 'gsub("\"", "\"") == 1 {x=$0; getline; print x " " $0;} gsub("\"", "\"") == 2 {print}' log

[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "one line [42]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines [13]"
[ 2020/08/12 11:40] Success with "two lines with a twist [19] to confuse you"
[ 2020/08/12 11:41] Failure with "one line again"
```

Comment: That isn't a safe way to use getline and it's not necessary (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) and would fail if there were more than 2 lines inside the quoted field.